# Why Does the location part dont work?

Tags: php

Index.php

```
    $password = hash('sha256', $pass); // password hashing using SHA256

     $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail='$email'");
     $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
     $count = mysql_num_rows($res); // if uname/pass correct it returns                                must be 1 row

     if( $count == 1 && $row['userPass']==$password ) {
     $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userId'];
     $_SESSION['location'] = $row['userLocation'];
    header("Location: home.php");
   } else {
    $errMSG = "Incorrect Login";
   }
```

Home.php

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM machines WHERE locatie=".$_SESSION['location']; 
 $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Why Does this not work??
I can't figure out why the `$_SESSION['locatie']` part does not work??
I thought it has the same value as in the other file.

Comment: You have to stop further process after header

Comment: do not use mysql functions. use mysqli or pdo

Comment: so the code will be header("Location: home.php");die; try this

Comment: Why should I use mysqli instead of MySQL??

Comment: @JelleN because mysql is no longer supported by the latest php versions

Comment: @JelleN _and_ because mysql is unsafe and vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @JelleN see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your mysql query.

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM machines WHERE locatie='".$_SESSION['location']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the `$_SESSION['location']` value to be carried over to the `home.php` file, after redirection?

Make sure that `$row['location']` has a value, and that `session_start()` has been invoked on both pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try Checking by debugging the code like this

```
print_r($row);
```

If Yes then again do this:

```
echo $row['userLocation'];
```

Are you getting this value?
Then If You want to put value into session and den redirect make sure you initialize the session first by writing `session_start();` and den add the value like

```
$_SESSION['location]= $row['userLocation];
```

But make sure check are you getting value before setting session.?
Better would be to solve if you update your code with `print_r($row);`
And please stop using sql functions as they are deprecated instead use mysqli and pdo .